# Exchange Web Service - Sending Email from other account

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exchangewebservices

Could anyone please let me know that can I use EWS Web Service API to send emails where the from address field shows some generic email address rather that the one I am using for sending them. For example:

Suppose, I am using xyz@domain.com to create a emails, now I need to send those emails where the from field should depict something like help@domain.com.

Can we achieve this using EWS API's??

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one of the method for doing so, [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) provides the details about it.

Although, I have accomplished what was need, but still want to know if it is possible to do using`EWS Web Service API's`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send from EWS if you have delegate permissions for the calling user (*acting on behalf of*) or have the credentials of the sending account (`WebCredentials`) when connecting to exchange service.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send messages from a mail address which is part of your organization. Exchange will prevent you from doing anything else. Additionally, you need the proper permission to use addresses which are not assigned to your mailbox.